# Using css to remove background

Tags: html, css

This the `html` code to create the button

```
  <div class="delete-style">
    <button type="button">DELETE</button>
  </div>
```

and am using this `css` code to remove the border surrounding the text in the `button`

```
.delete-style {
    background-color: red;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    outline: None;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

[image: result]

Comment: You are styling the div, not the button itself- those are basics

Comment: if you want to style the button, use `.delete-style button {`

Answer (score 1):

To remove border around the button you can add `border : None;` style to your button

```css
.delete-style {
    background-color: red;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    outline: None;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.delete-style button {
 border: None;
}
```

```html
  <div class="delete-style">
    <button type="button">DELETE</button>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to style the div, not button. declare class to the button, it will work.

```
<div>
    <button type="button" class="delete-style">DELETE</button>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This will help you
.delete-style button{border:0;}